# Updating/replacing GeoTiff data store on file system causes GeoServer to halt

Tags: raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I have a few hundred raster layers that are updated at least 4 times a day.

The GeoTiff's are updated directly on disc.

I'm running it as a windows service and I can sell the wrapper app logging the 
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.

The raster are in GeoTiff format, and it looks like a error to do with the files being updated causes GeoServer to fail and hang.

I cannot upload via the REST API as GeoTiff is not support, 
I might be able get the wrapper to restart geoserver,

Also a smaller percentage of Shapefiles are also updated at the sametime, but I can tell from the logs it's more likely to do with the Raster layers

How can I  deploy raster data on windows, as a service, and to be able to update the raster data without having to restart the geoserver service wrapper?

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know why? Do you want to develop a fix for the problem in GeoServer? Do you want a deployment option that doesn't cause the fault?

Comment: I'd like to have confirmation why it's a problem and to have any workaround for deploying raster data on windows, as a service, and to be able to update the raster data without having to restart the geoserver service wrapper